# To add members to ASYNCCOMPLETEDEVENTARGS

Tags: silverlight

how can i add a member in ASYNCCOMPLETEDEVENTARGS in System.ComponentModel
please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use userstate. When you callMehotdAsync(..) there is overload for where you can pass object userstate and you can get that userstate from ASYNCCOMPLETEDEVENTARGS

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "add member"?

- If you're using WCF/ASMX service, the service reference client will generate typed AsyncCompletedEventArgs, which will add the return (and ref/out parameter) values of your service call to the completed eventargs
- If you're raising the AsyncCompleted event yourself, subclass (inherit from) AsyncCompletedEventArgs (so you can add anything to it) and raise it with your custom type
- If you just need some data in the eventHandling code, which you posess on the BeginAsync call, then as previously mentioned the userstate is a safe bet.